# How to dynamically set properties to a template (including css) PHP

Tags: php, css, templates, properties

I have to do a website that allows an admin to create "events" where other users can registrate in.
Each "event" has its own users.
The thing when the admin is creating the event he has to choose  a Design from predefined templates (that I created before of course), When I say desing I mean the position of the menus and other stuff.
But here is the "problem", The admin choose from a colour palette the background or text color for a menu, for example.

As every design template has its own CSS File, i dont know how to set the background to a specific area of the "event" created before.

I was thinking that when i get the colour choosed, i can put it into a DB with the "event", and when someones wants to see the event, i get it from the DB, use the file_gets_contents of PHP and replace the {Here is some propertie value} with the color value. What do you think?.
Is there another way to do it? 
Thanks for your time answering and remembering :D

Answer (score 2):

Save the custom color values in a database or something.  Then just set those CSS properties in a `style` tag in the html header.  That way you only have to set the properties that can change in one place.

Something like :

```
<style type="text/css">
custom_text_color  { color: $prop1_color; }
custom_background { background-color: $prop2_color; }
</style>
```

Then just the following html output would stay the same later in the page:

```
<span class="custom_text_color">This is text in your custom color!</span>
```

Comment: Don't even modify it in the html header. Save the style sheet as a `.php`, add `header("Content-type: text/css", true);` to the php file and use sessions to determine the reference id in order to pull information from the database. (modify your original answer)

Comment: I thought about recommending that -- but I think considering the question that might be a bit too sophisticated.  Especially when you get into checking to see if a file exists already, refreshing cached files correctly, etc.  Writing a file on every page request is what I bet this user would do, which is bad.

Comment: Well, I still suggest it. OP can look at the comments and decide what he wants to do.

Comment: Yeah gavin's answer seems simple and nice, Thanks you both for answering, I think I'll definitely do that ;) see ya.

Comment: @rentless, Remember to accept this answer if it works for you.